# Is volatile int faster than AtomicInteger

Tags: java

I am doing currently a sample exercise and i found one weird  observation that if I replace AutomicInteger with volatile program runs faster. Note : I am only doing read operations.

code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {

AtomicInteger integer  = new AtomicInteger(100000000);
// volatile int integer= 100000000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
// We will store the threads so that we can check if they are done
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Main main = new Main();
// We will create 500 threads

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  Runnable task = new MyRunnable(main.integer);
  Thread worker = new Thread(task);
  // We can set the name of the thread
  worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
  // Start the thread, never call method run() direct
  worker.start();
  // Remember the thread for later usage
  threads.add(worker);
}
int running = 0;
do {
  running = 0;
  for (Thread thread : threads) {
    if (thread.isAlive()) {
      running++;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("We have " + running + " running threads. ");
} while (running > 0);

System.out.println("Total Time Required :" +(System.currentTimeMillis()- start));
}
}
```

MyRunnable class:

```
 import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
private final AtomicInteger countUntil;

MyRunnable(AtomicInteger countUntil) {
    this.countUntil = countUntil;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < countUntil.intValue(); i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Time Required for this program to run using AutomicInteger on my machine.

> Total Time Required :102169
>
> Total Time Required :90375

Time required for this program to run using volatile on my machine

> Total Time Required :66760
>
> Total Time Required :71773

Does this mean volatile is faster than AutomicInteger for read operation also?

Comment: If you are doing only read operations why do you need to worry about synchronization/

Comment: @thinksteep As I mentioned its just a sample exercise. What surprised me was there was time difference even if read operations are performed.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` exists to make it easy to do _compound_ atomic operations on integers, such as `addAndGet`, `getAndAdd`, `getAndSet`, etc. If you don't need those operations then you should just stick with a `volatile int` because—as Tomasz Nurkiewicz explained in his answer—`AtomicInteger` is implemented on top of a `volatile int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` in read context is basically a thin wrapper around `volatile int`:

```
private volatile int value;

public final int get() {
    return value;
}

public int intValue() {
    return get();
}
```

Don't expect the wrapper to be faster then the wrapped value taken alone. It can only be *as fast as* the `volatile int` if inlining is employed by the JVM.

---

And hint: if you are "*only doing read operations*", this will be even faster:

```
static final int integer= 100000000;
```

Comment: I created custom wrapper to verify and Yes its the reason.

Comment: @AmitDeshpande: so you get the same timings as with `AtomicInteger`? Can you share your microbenchmark results?

Comment: First Run 1: Total Time Required :93059 Second Run : Total Time Required :80608

Answer (score 1):

This question depends on the particular JVM, hardware, and operating system, so the only possible answer is 'maybe'.

Answer (score 1):

> Is volatile int faster than AtomicInteger

The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles, as stated in [section 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of The Java™ Language Specification. Followings are draw back of volatile int compare to Atomic type.

- get has the memory effects of reading a volatile variable.
- set has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable.
- lazySet has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable except that it permits reorderings with subsequent (but not previous) memory actions that do not themselves impose reordering constraints with ordinary non-volatile writes. Among other usage contexts, lazySet may apply when nulling out, for the sake of garbage collection, a reference that is never accessed again.
- weakCompareAndSet atomically reads and conditionally writes a variable but does not create any happens-before orderings, so provides no guarantees with respect to previous or subsequent reads and writes of any variables other than the target of the weakCompareAndSet.
- compareAndSet and all other read-and-update operations such as getAndIncrement have the memory effects of both reading and writing volatile variables.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a volatile int is faster than an AtomicInteger, should there will be very few applications where this is noticeable. Still, AtomicInteger offers a wider set of potential uses.